# iptables from execve c function not accepting flags

Tags: iptables, c

When I run

```
$ /usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

from the command line it works fine. However when I compile and run this code

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char *args[6];
    args[0] = "/usr/sbin/iptables";
    args[1] = "-I INPUT";
    args[2] = "-p tcp";
    args[3] = "--dport 80";
    args[4] = "-j ACCEPT";
    args[5] = NULL;
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);
}
```

I get the following output

```
$ ./code
iptables v1.4.6: unknown protocol ` tcp' specified
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I tried removing the space

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char *args[6];
    args[0] = "/usr/sbin/iptables";
    args[1] = "-I INPUT";
    args[2] = "-ptcp";
    args[3] = "--dport 80";
    args[4] = "-j ACCEPT";
    args[5] = NULL;
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);
}
```

and I got

```
$./code
iptables v1.4.6: unknown option `--dport 80'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Can anyone help me out here? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the help output

```
$ iptables --help
iptables v1.4.6

Usage: iptables -[AD] chain rule-specification [options]
       iptables -I chain [rulenum] rule-specification [options]
       iptables -R chain rulenum rule-specification [options]
       iptables -D chain rulenum [options]
       iptables -[LS] [chain [rulenum]] [options]
       iptables -[FZ] [chain] [options]
       iptables -[NX] chain
       iptables -E old-chain-name new-chain-name
       iptables -P chain target [options]
       iptables -h (print this help information)

Commands:
Either long or short options are allowed.
  --append  -A chain        Append to chain
  --delete  -D chain        Delete matching rule from chain
  --delete  -D chain rulenum
                Delete rule rulenum (1 = first) from chain
  --insert  -I chain [rulenum]
                Insert in chain as rulenum (default 1=first)
  --replace -R chain rulenum
                Replace rule rulenum (1 = first) in chain
  --list    -L [chain [rulenum]]
                List the rules in a chain or all chains
  --list-rules -S [chain [rulenum]]
                Print the rules in a chain or all chains
  --flush   -F [chain]      Delete all rules in  chain or all chains
  --zero    -Z [chain [rulenum]]
                Zero counters in chain or all chains
  --new     -N chain        Create a new user-defined chain
  --delete-chain
            -X [chain]      Delete a user-defined chain
  --policy  -P chain target
                Change policy on chain to target
  --rename-chain
            -E old-chain new-chain
                Change chain name, (moving any references)
Options:
[!] --proto -p proto    protocol: by number or name, eg. `tcp'
[!] --source    -s address[/mask][...]
                source specification
[!] --destination -d address[/mask][...]
                destination specification
[!] --in-interface -i input name[+]
                network interface name ([+] for wildcard)
 --jump -j target
                target for rule (may load target extension)
  --goto      -g chain
                              jump to chain with no return
  --match   -m match
                extended match (may load extension)
  --numeric -n      numeric output of addresses and ports
[!] --out-interface -o output name[+]
                network interface name ([+] for wildcard)
  --table   -t table    table to manipulate (default: `filter')
  --verbose -v      verbose mode
  --line-numbers        print line numbers when listing
  --exact   -x      expand numbers (display exact values)
[!] --fragment  -f      match second or further fragments only
  --modprobe=<command>      try to insert modules using this command
  --set-counters PKTS BYTES set the counter during insert/append
[!] --version   -V      print package version.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your arguments in the same way the shell would:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char *args[10];
    int i = 0;
    args[i++] = "/usr/sbin/iptables";
    args[i++] = "-I";
    args[i++] = "INPUT";
    args[i++] = "-p";
    args[i++] = "tcp";
    args[i++] = "--dport";
    args[i++] = "80";
    args[i++] = "-j";
    args[i++] = "ACCEPT";
    args[i++] = NULL;
    execve(args[0], args, NULL);
}
```

The shell splits on *all* spaces.

Comment: Great! That's what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: That variable index increment for a statically declared array, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

The flags and their arguments should be separate:

```
int main() {
    char *args[] = {
      "/usr/sbin/iptables",
      "-I", "INPUT",
      "-ptcp",
      "--dport", "80",
      "-j", "ACCEPT",
      NULL
    };
...
}
```

For commands where the option and option argument can be given as a single argument, there shouldn't be a space between them (e.g., `tail` and `-n6`), or have a separator like `=` depending on the command, e.g. `grep` and `--color=always`.

Comment: @stephen-kitt just beat you to it, thanks anyway!